# How to handle jsoup when erroneous url text is used and can't connect?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have searched and searched and read and tested....including: /6557673/jsoup-cant-extract-stock-price-from-the-webpage - which is the closest issue I found, but my perspective is a bit different. 
I'm scraping text from urls with dynamic content. Only the last segment of the url varies, such as is done here with question numbers. My issue is that if I enter a page number that doesn't exist, I get an instant crash, such as: 'The application has stopped unexpectedly'. It logs 'String index out of range -1' which makes sense.

Is there a way I can do something like a regex inString check before executing that line?

My url string looks like this:

```
"http://whatever.website.com/ + dypageno + ".html";
```

and the section of code:

```
try{
    doc = Jsoup.connect(srchStr).get();
        if (doc == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not locate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
   }else{
   String grabbedtxt = doc.select("h1").text();
   String grabbed=grabbedtxt.substring(grabbedtxt.indexOf("$"));
   grabbed = "Response Today:\r \n \r \n" + grabbed + "\r \n \r \n";
   et.setText(grabbed);}    
   }
catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            et.setText("Page not found.");
        }
}
```

As I stated, this works fine until a bad url is used. I've tried limiting the try/catch to only the connect statement, different exceptions, etc to no avail. 
I already have a shaven head, so I have no hair to pull out! Can anyone suggest that I learn something here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you should check if `grabbedtxt` is an empty `String`. The

```
doc.select ("h1").text ()
```

may return an empty `String` if `h1` tag does not exist. The following code illustrates this:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><head/><body/></html");
        String grabbedtxt = doc.select("h1").text();
        if (grabbedtxt.contains("$")) {
            String grabbed = grabbedtxt.substring(grabbedtxt.indexOf("$"));
            System.out.println("Response Today: " + grabbed);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No response!");
        }
    }
}
```

This will print `No response!`.